# Construction of parallel lengths in given ratio

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, angle

**An angle is given and two points $M$ and $N$  inside it. Through these two points, draw  parallel lines $m$ and $n$ so that lengths formed by their intersections with the angle arms are in  ratio 1:3.**

I tried solving it with homothety but it didn't quite work out. I would appreciate any hints.

[image]

One solution :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let the vertex of the angle be $A$. Mark point $P$ on $\overrightarrow{AM}$ such that $|MP|=2|AM|$. Then $\overleftrightarrow{NP}$ must be the line $n$. Can you find line $m$ ? Why does the construction work  and is it unique ?

Comment: Yes, I can. After the construction of line $n$, the construction of line $m$ is trivial because it's just a parallel line to line $n$ passing through $M$. The construction works because lines $m$ and $n$ along with the angle arms,  form similar triangles of the similarity coefficient 1:3 which is achieved by the construction of  point $P$ such that $|AM|/|AP|=1/3$.

Comment: The solution is not unique because we can also reverse the roles of points $M$ and $N$, and find a point $P'$ on the line $AN$ such that 
$|AN|:|AP'|=1/3 $ and then construct line $P'M$. Now the second required line is parallel to line $P'M$ and also passing through point $N$. These lines will also form lengths of the ratio 1:3 on the extensions of the angle arms.

Comment: I added the picture of the other solution to my original post. You have been nothing but helpful and educational. Thank you sir/mam

Comment: I am glad that you found it helpful :)